# How do I filter NSArray with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my array there are different kind of values some might be a string or object or Key-Value type.

**In this example array contains NSString, NSObject and NSDictionary type of values.**

```
example : ContactName[0] "ABC"
          ContactName[1] = XYZ
          ContactName[2] = (
                             {
                                language = @"en"
                                value = "PQR"
                             },
                             {
                                language = @"de"
                                value = "QWERTY"
                             }
                          )
```

So finally can anyone help me to filter such type of array's, using NSPredicate

I want to filter it as user type first keyword in `UISearchBar`.

Please help me I'm new to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark - Search delegate methods

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText

{

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@",searchText];

    searchResult = [_kDropDownOption filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    [_kTableView reloadData];

}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    if (searchBar.text.length == 0) {
        searchEnabled = NO;
        [_kTableView reloadData];
    }
    else {
        searchEnabled = YES;
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchBar.text];

        NSLog(@"%@",self->searchResult);
    }
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    searchEnabled = YES;

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchBar.text];

}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchBar setText:@""];
    searchEnabled = NO;
    [_kTableView reloadData];


}
```

Comment: searchresult & _kdropdwnoption are NSArray                                          _ktableview is UITableview

Comment: It gives me this error : Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string

Comment: Error : this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key language.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uMgn38GTD4aV6RIualfnCEZFZyYVgN64                 take project from here